# How to prevent certain windows from rotating with the Compiz cube?

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm using Compiz in Ubuntu 16.04. When I rotate the cube, both the Unity launcher and the title bar keep fixed.

So, my question is: Is it possible to extend that behavior to other objects? In particular, I would like notifications and the Yakuake terminal to remain still when rotating the cube.

In the Beryl era it was possible. You could specify which windows would keep static.